# Casting Data Types When Converting a CSV file to a Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

I have a CSV file that looks like this

```
Item,Price,Calories,Category
Orange,1.99,60,Fruit
Cereal,3.99,110,Box Food
Ice Cream,6.95,200,Dessert
...
```

and I want to form a Python dictionary in this format:

```
{'Orange': (1.99, 60, 'Fruit'), 'Cereal': (3.99, 110, 'Box Food'), ... }
```

***I want to make sure the titles of the columns are removed (i.e., the first row is NOT included).***

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
reader = csv.reader(open('storedata.csv'))

for row in reader:
    # only needed if empty lines in input
    if not row:
        continue
    key = row[0]
    x = float(row[1])
    y = int(row[2])
    z = row[3]
    result[key] = x, y, z

print(result)
```

However, when I do this, I get a `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Price'`, and I don't know how to fix it. *I want to keep these three values in a tuple.*

Thanks!

Comment: What this error means is that in the column price. There are some rows that contain string like. show us a sample data of the `reader`. If this is a `dataframe` can you use the `.info()` method on the reader.

Comment: @PandasJ I just converted it into a pandas DataFrame. Here is the info: `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 4 columns):
0    4 non-null object
1    4 non-null object
2    4 non-null object
3    4 non-null object
dtypes: object(4)
memory usage: 256.0+ bytes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using `pandas.read_csv` to read your `csv` file:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([["Orange",1.99,60,"Fruit"], ["Cereal",3.99,110,"Box Food"], ["Ice Cream",6.95,200,"Dessert"]],
            columns= ["Item","Price","Calories","Category"])
```

I have tried to frame your data as shown below:

```py
print(df)
```

```
    Item         Price    Calories    Category
0   Orange       1.99       60          Fruit
1   Cereal       3.99       110         Box Food
2   Ice Cream    6.95       200         Dessert
```

First off, you create an empty `Python dictionary` to hold the files then leverage the `pandas.DataFrame.iterrows()` to iterate through the columns

```
res = {}


for index, row in df.iterrows():
    item = row["Item"]
    x = pd.to_numeric(row["Price"], errors="coerce")
    y = int(row["Calories"])
    z = row["Category"]
    res[item] = (x,y,z)
```

In fact printing `res` results in your `expected output` as shown below:

```
print(res)

{'Orange': (1.99, 60, 'Fruit'),
 'Cereal': (3.99, 110, 'Box Food'),
 'Ice Cream': (6.95, 200, 'Dessert')}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use `dict` plus `zip` if you're using a `pandas.DataFrame` called `df`:

```py
>>> dict(zip(df['Item'], df[['Price', 'Calories', 'Category']].values.tolist()))
{'Orange': [1.99, 60, 'Fruit'], 'Cereal': [3.99, 110, 'Box Food'], 'Ice Cream': [6.95, 200, 'Dessert']}
```

Comment: I want to have the other items in a tuple, not a list.

Comment: Downvoted for what? If you want to convert the values to a tuple, it's as simple as this: `dict(zip(df['Item'], map(tuple, df[['Price', 'Calories', 'Category']].values.tolist())))`